# After restart ZSH cannot find NPM, Gulp or Bower

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

**Context**

Earlier this week, while my computer was starting Ubuntu 17.10 it shutoff due to low battery.

**The Problem**

Upon plugging in and rebooting I noticed some unusual behavior. One of the key things was that [Oh My ZSH](http://ohmyz.sh/) appears to be broken. Meaning, when I opened Terminal, pressed the up arrow to cycle through my history, and hit enter to execute the command: it reported it could not find my ZSH history log and failed to execute the command.

**What I've Tried**

So I assumed that ZSH was corrupted as a consequence of the improper shut down. So I reinstalled and the history error disappeared. But then it couldn't find `NPM`, `Gulp` or `Bower`. Meaning, when I executed something like `gulp watch` it reports `zsh: command not found: gulp`.

So I attempted to reinstall `gulp` with `NPM` and it reported the same error but for `NPM`.

I concluded that they were still installed and not corrupted but that `ZSH` simply can't find them.

So I tried a random command to export "paths" from a `bash` file to my ZSH file (I think they're called .rc files but I don't remember).

Then it seems to work.

Then I closed Terminal and it stopped working.

So I reinstalled ZSH again, this time using `apt-get` and it worked without having to export my paths.

Then I restarted (properly) and discovered it's broken again.

**The Question**

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

short answer: add path in your ~/.zshrc
tl;dr
find executable path for your libraries or programs and add them 
nano ~/.zshrc
export PATH=/path/to/lib/or/bin:$PATH

then save the file (ctl+o)

after this restart your zsh or reload the rc file (**source ~/.zshrc**)